# Excel 2013 VBA: Setting activeworkbook when clicking between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with a userform that contains a listbox that is used to populate data on a sheet.

If I have multiple workbooks open and I click from one workbook directly to the listbox on the userform in the other workbook, the ListBox_Change event fires before Activeworkbook changes to reflect the workbook that contains the userform.  So when the code reaches `Set EqDataSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Equipment-Data")` I get a subscript out of range error because the workbook I'm coming from doesn't contain a sheet named "Equipment-Data".

What is the best way to set the ActiveWorkbook to the parent of the userform?  Thoughts I've had are setting a public variable `wb = ActiveWorkbook` on workbook_open or just trapping Err.Number=9 and telling the user to click on the sheet before clicking the userform.  I'm sure there is something simple I am completely overlooking (VBA amateur).

Thoughts?

Comment: Why work with `ActiveWorkbook` at all? Keep a reference to the `Workbook` objects you're working with, and use those.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `activeworkbook` use `thisworkbook` which returns the workbook in which the code resides.

To make it active `thisworkbook.activate` should work

Comment: Note: this only works if the UserForm operates against `ThisWorkbook`. If it needs to operate against other workbook(s) being *active* at runtime (not enough detail in OP to say definitively), this may not work, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't be much simpler!  To answer @DavidZemens, the workbook with the userform is entirely self contained, i.e. does not act on any other workbook.

Comment: @MattD then that approach will work in *this* instance, but it will not work in more complicated scenarios you might encounter in the future :)

Comment: @MattD you shouldn't need to `Activate` it at all, you can simply refer to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets...` instead of `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets...` and that way it will work without needing to explicitly make any sheet active. There are other reasons why you may want to activate a sheet, from a UI or design perspective, but it's definitely not necessary to do so.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks! I did a a find/replace ActiveWorkbook with ThisWorkbook in my module since it will work for this sheet. I'll have to do some studying about when it is best to use each.

Comment: It's never best to rely on `ActiveWorkbook`, `Select`, `Selection`, etc.. In some cases it's *easier*, but it's never *better*. [Detailed explanation and how to avoid those things, here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).